# Lost the contents of my inventory

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Today I was playing Minecraft Pocket Edition, and decided to take a quick break for five minutes. I saved and quit, then closed the app. I come back five minutes later to have all of the items in my inventory gone. Nothing remains. I ran back to my house, my chest still had everything, but my inventory contained nothing. I had so much important stuff in my inventory, including all the wool I had to make a bed. Even all of my iron tools. I’m devastated.

EDIT: I have no memory of even writing this post. Sorry guys!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what your question actually is? Do you want to know WHY this happened? Or how you can prevent it? Or something completely different?

Comment: If you're fine with it, you can enable cheats and use commands to give yourself your items back. Otherwise, I'm not sure what can be done unless you have a backup of your world somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

I had this happen once as well, if your world doesn't have cheats enabled, there isn't much you can do.

It is never a good idea to carry all of your iron on you at once, especially not on PE as the worlds tend to be pretty glitchy.

However, Iron and Wool aren't that rare in a Minecraft world. 
Just find more stuff, and move on. It may seem frustrating as a bug, but items can be replaced, as can worlds.